# get a line with regex

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble doing simple things with regex in dot net.
Suppose I want to find all lines that contain the word "pizza".  I would think I would do the following:

```
^ .* pizza .* $
```

The idea is the first character indicates the start of a line, the dollar sign indicates the end of the line, and the dot-star indicates any number of characters.
This doesn't seem to work.

Then I tried something else that doesn't work either.  I thought I would find all routines in my visual basic project that start with "Sub Page_Load" and end with "End Sub". I did a search for:

```
 Sub Page_Load .* End Sub
```

But this found pretty much EVERY subroutine in the project.
In other words, it didn't limit itself to the Page_Load sub.
So I thought I'd be smart and notice that every End Sub is at the end of a line, so all I have to do is put a $ after it like this:

```
 Sub Page_Load .* End Sub$
```

But that finds absolutely zero strings.
So what am I doing wrong? (one note, I put extra blanks around .* here so you can see it, but normally the blanks would not be there.

Comment: do you need also the text before and after 'pizza' in each line? Also I think your regex won't match if 'pizza' is in the beginning or the end (because of whitespaces).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, now complete new answer.

1. Search for the word "pizza" (not "pizzas")

   1. If you have a Multiline string and want to find a single row, you need to use the Option `[Multiline][1]`. That changes the behaviour of the anchors `^` and `$` to match the start and the end of the row.
   2. To ensure to match only the complete word "pizza" and no partial match, use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
   3. If you don't use the Singleline option, you don't need to worry about greediness

   So your regex would be:

   ```
   Regex optionRegex = new Regex(@"^.*\bpizza\b.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
   ```
2. For the `Sub Page_Load.*End Sub` thing, you need to match more than one line:

   1. Use the [single line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Singleline) option, to allow the `.` match also newline characters.
   2. You need ungreedy matching behaviour of the [quantifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx)

   So your regex would be:

   ```
   Regex optionRegex = new Regex(@"Sub Page_Load.*?End Sub", RegexOptions.Singleline);
   ```

Comment: There's also the possibility to use the `x` modifier if the flavor he's using supports it.

Comment: I'm not saying he may be using it, but that he may use it. That wasn't a reproach nor anything like that, just some more information.

Comment: I think the 'greedy' option is part of the answer, but also I notice that dot-net uses options that change the meaning of "$" and "^".  That seems to be part of the problem too, i.e.
rOptions |= RegexOptions.Multiline;

                rOptions |= RegexOptions.Singleline;

Comment: @GideonIsaac, you don't give enough details, to give a real answer. Are you using any options? The "pizza" part, are you searching row by row or does your input string has multiple rows? I haven't seen your last sentence, when I answered. Why the heck do you insert blanks? They do change the meaning of the regex.

Comment: @GideonIsaac I changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you may need non-greedy approach. try this:

`^.*?pizza.*$`

Comment: What's the logic behind this suggestion?

Comment: well, `?` is used to find with `non-greedy` approach (as opposed to the default greedy approach).

Comment: for example: `<a>hello world</a>..<a>good night</a>`. to search this, regular regex `/<a>.*</a>/` will result in this whole string. so you will need `/<a>.*?<\/a>/` and it will stop the search at the first occurance of `</a>`

Comment: Yeah thanks for the explanation, but what's the point here? He wants to search for every line with pizza, using a lazy operator won't change the result **at all**.

Comment: I think the 'greedy' option is part of the answer for one of the problems: (the Page_Load example), but also I notice that dot-net uses options that change the meaning of "$" and "^".  That seems to be part of the problem too, i.e.
rOptions |= RegexOptions.Multiline vs SingleLine